# Add spaces to words in textfile

Tags: c

I have a simple textfile containing:

```
dog
bear
panda
fish
elephant
```

However, I want all of them to have a full 10 characters.

Thus I want to fill the rest of the word with 'x' like:

```
dogxxxxxxx
bearxxxxxx
pandaxxxxx
fishxxxxxx
elephantxx
```

What I have so far is:

```
int filterWords(){
    FILE *ptr_file;
    FILE *ptr_file2;
    char buf[1000];
    int i = 0;
    int numberSpaces;

    ptr_file =fopen("animals.txt","r");
    if (!ptr_file)
        return 1;

    while (fgets(buf,1000, ptr_file)!=NULL){
        if(strlen(buf) < 10){
            numberSpaces = 10 - strlen(buf)-1;
            memset(buf, 'x', numberSpaces);
            buf[strlen(buf)+numberSpaces] = '\0';
            ptr_file2 = fopen("newAnimal.txt", "a");
            fputs(buf, ptr_file2);
            fclose(ptr_file2);
        } 
    }

    fclose(ptr_file);
        return 0;
}
```

However, when I tried to open the `newAnimal.txt`, I got something like this:

```
dog
xxxbxxxear
pandaxxxf
ishxxxxxx
....
```

All are mislocated. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Don't forget that `fgets()` includes the newline in the data it returns.  That messes up the lengths and also the position of the padding.

Comment: `fopen()` is a heavy-duty function call; it takes quite a lot of time.  You do not want to be calling it in a loop as you do.

Comment: But strlen(buf) is still the actual #bytes.

Comment: @JimBaldwin: Yes, `strlen(buf)` counts the bytes in the line, including the newline.  So, the line containing `dog` has a length of 4 because `strlen()` counts the newline too.  You're right about the position of the `memset()` being wrong.  And there's a major problem with the line `buf[strlen(buf)+numberSpaces] = '\0';` — no-one knows what `strlen(buf)` is at that point (at least, not reliably).

Comment: Are you sure?  "The C library function size_t strlen(const char *str) computes the length of the string str up to, but not including the terminating null character.:

Comment: (from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strlen.htm)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128594/discussion-between-jonathan-leffler-and-jim-baldwin).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ah you are right the fgets(). So what should I use then?

Comment: Use `fgets()`, but remember that `strlen(buf)` will count the newline too.  You'll also need to take into account what Jim Baldwin has said.  I'm not sure if you can join the chat - probably not, I'm sorry to say.  If you can, it might be worth looking at what has been said.

Comment: Do you want to ignore (delete) 'East African Lion', which is longer than 10?  Or 'Hippopotamus'?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes. But so far I only have animal names that are shorter than 10 chars

Comment: Also, you mention spaces but you're using `x`'s — do you mean spaces or x's?  Spaces is trivial (after you get rid of the newline): `printf("%-10s\n", buf)` would deal with that, and print any longer names unpadded.  But you don't get a choice of padding; it is blanks or nothing.

Comment: You should open the second file once, before the loop, and then write to it (probably outside of the `if` statement), and close the second file (and the first file) after the loop completes.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I still haven;t decided whether to go with 'x'  or ' '. I think they are both using the same concept right?

Comment: If you're using `memset()`, the choice of pad is immaterial; `'x'` and `' '` are equivalent (to each other, and `'@'` and any other printing character).  If you use `printf()` to pad, then space is mandatory and `'x'` is not an option.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I updated the code with Jim's advice below and I still got a funky output.  Example: `bearxxxx^Adragonxxxxx`. Furthermore, my panda still panda instead of `pandaxxxxxx`

Comment: You now have 3 answers.  I've not run the other two (neither is a full MCVE), but I believe they're both likely to work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is a number of off-by-one and similar logic errors conspiring against you. Let us take a look at that `if` statement in your main loop and see what's wrong:

```
if(strlen(buf) < 10){
    numberSpaces = 10 - strlen(buf)-1;
    memset(buf, 'x', numberSpaces);
    buf[strlen(buf)+numberSpaces] = '\0';
    ptr_file2 = fopen("newAnimal.txt", "a");
    fputs(buf, ptr_file2);
    fclose(ptr_file2);
}
```

First remember that fgets will store the newline, so buf will have an extra newline on it. This will increase is length (from strlen) by 1. So we have to adjust:

```
if (strlen(buf) < 11) {
    numberSpaces = 10 - (strlen(buf)-1); // otherwise - is done from the total, not from strlen
    memset(buf, 'x', numberSpaces); // still wrong...
    buf[strlen(buf)+numberSpaces] = '\0'; // still wrong...
    // fopen/fclose EVERY loop is terribly inefficient, but not wrong per se
    ptr_file2 = fopen("newAnimal.txt", "a");
    fputs(buf, ptr_file2);
    fclose(ptr_file2);
}
```

Now we need to fix our memset bufset issues because we don't want to memset the start of the string with 'x', but rather the end. Similarly we don't want to end with a '\0' we want '\n\0'. We also want to toss that immediately at the end, not after an additional numberSpaces wait...

```
if (strlen(buf) < 11) {
    numberSpaces = 10 - (strlen(buf)-1); 
    memset(buf + (strlen(buf)-1), 'x', numberSpaces); // now it will start from the correct spot
    buf[10] = '\n'; // we know how long we want our string to be ;)
    buf[11] = '\0';
    // fopen/fputs/fclose here (or outside the loop if you can)
}
```

One last thing to note: you should make sure your buffer is filled with 0 before you start using it... just turn the line `char buf[1000];` into `char buf[1000] = {0};` to be safe.

Another, more elegant, solution involves using strcspn to remove the newline only when applicable via `buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = '\0';`. `strcspn` is not a well-known function, but it searches for the character(s) provided and returns the index of the first occurance. It also takes the '\0' into account, so if it finds nothing it will return the length of the string. After correcting for the newline you don't need to subtract 1 from all the strlen calls anymore.

Comment: You are right! I was so careless when I wrote this code. I should've paid more attention to the memory location. It all make sense now. Thank you.

Comment: IMO, better to remove the _likely_, but not certain `'\n'` from `buf` before the initial `if (strlen(buf) < some_value)`.  This will help code work, even if the last line does not end with a `'\n'`.

Answer (score 2):

For starters,

```
memset(buf, 'x', numberSpaces);
```

should be

```
memset(&buf[strlen(buf)], 'x', numberSpaces);
```

Also, you're calculating numberSpaces wrong.  Instead of:

```
numberSpaces = 10 - strlen(buf)-1;
```

It should be:

```
numberSpaces = 10 - strlen(buf);
```

With that corrected, you need to put the \0 in the right place.  Instead of:

```
buf[strlen(buf)+numberSpaces] = '\0';
```

It becomes:

```
buf[strlen(buf)] = '\0';
```

Your while loop now looks like:

```
while (fgets(buf,1000, ptr_file)!=NULL){
    if(strlen(buf) < 10){
        numberSpaces = 10 - strlen(buf);
        memset(&buf[strlen(buf), 'x', numberSpaces);
        buf[strlen(buf)] = '\0';
        ptr_file2 = fopen("newAnimal.txt", "a");
        fputs(buf, ptr_file2);
        fclose(ptr_file2);
    } 
}
```

Comment: what about the fgets? I think that's the main issue.

Comment: I tried to modified using your input. The output still really funky. Example: `bearxxxx^Adragonxxxxx`

Comment: Been debugging and updating.  Had a bug in the memset line.  Updated it in the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the help! My code now is similar to yours.

Comment: Happy to help.  There are definitely simpler ways to do what you're doing, but I think it's more fun to debug it the way you set off to do it.

Comment: Yes I agree. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

And a third offering…take note of what's in here, but choose one of the others as the accepted answer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static int filterWords(const char *ifile, const char *ofile)
{
    FILE *ptr_file1 = fopen(ifile, "r");
    if (!ptr_file1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file %s for reading\n", ifile);
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *ptr_file2 = fopen(ofile, "w");
    if (!ptr_file2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file %s for writing\n", ofile);
        fclose(ptr_file1);
        return 1;
    }

    char buf[1000];
    while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), ptr_file1) != NULL)
    {
        buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = '\0';
        int len = strlen(buf);
        if (len < 10)
        {
            memset(buf + len, 'x', 10 - len);
            buf[10] = '\0';
        }
        fprintf(ptr_file2, "%s\n", buf);
    }

    fclose(ptr_file1);
    fclose(ptr_file2);
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("Status: %d\n", filterWords("animals.txt", "newAnimal.txt"));
    return 0;
}
```

Notes:

- I've passed the file names to the function, rather than hard-coding them.  This also makes it easier to report errors; you can identify the file.
- Errors should be reported on the standard error channel, of course.
- Personally, I find the (common) asymmetry between `ptr_file` and `ptr_file2` annoying; I use `ptr_file` for one, but then use `ptr_file1` and `ptr_file2` when I need the two names.  Actually, for file pointers, I'd usually use either `fp1` and `fp2` or `ifp` and `ofp`, but I kept closer to the original code this time.
- This code checks that both files are opened successfully; your code assumed that the second file could be opened each time and would (probably) crash if it suddenly couldn't be opened.
- I'm assuming a C99 compiler so variables can be defined when needed; if you're stuck with a C90 compiler, move the declarations to the top and change my initializations into assignments.
- I use the `buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = '\0';` notation to safely zap the first (and only) newline in the buffer.
- I then calculate the length of the line once.
- If the line is shorter than 10, then I use `memset()` to set the trailing part to `x`'s and add a null byte.
- The thrice-repeated `10` should be a named constant, such as:

  ```
  enum { PAD_LENGTH = 10 };
  ```
- The code opens the secondary file once and writes all the names, even those not needing any padding, to the file.
- Both files are explicitly closed.
- Paranoid code would check that the output file was closed successfully and report problems if there are any.
- You could decide whether to report errors on the input file too — you might use `ferror()` to detect errors on the input.
- In other circumstances, I might use POSIX's [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) to read the line.  One big advantage is that it returns the number of characters in the line, so you don't have to search for the newline in the same way (though the last line of a file without a trailing newline needs to be worried about).

Input:

```
dog
bear
panda
fish
elephant
alligator
rhinoceros
hippopotamus
East African Lion
```

Output:

```
dogxxxxxxx
bearxxxxxx
pandaxxxxx
fishxxxxxx
elephantxx
alligatorx
rhinoceros
hippopotamus
East African Lion
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! I will add this feature into my code.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will solve your issue:

```
int filterWords(void)
{
    FILE *ptr_file;
    FILE *ptr_file2;
    char buf[1000];
    int strLen = 0;
    int numberSpaces;

    ptr_file = fopen("animals.txt","r");
    if (!ptr_file)
        return 1;

    while (fgets(buf, 1000, ptr_file)!=NULL)
    {
        strLen = strlen(buf) - 1;
        if(strLen < 10){
            numberSpaces = 10 - (strLen);
            memset(&buf[strLen], 'x', numberSpaces);
            buf[strLen + numberSpaces] = '\n';
            buf[strLen + numberSpaces + 1] = '\0';
            ptr_file2 = fopen("newAnimal.txt", "a");
            fputs(buf, ptr_file2);
            fclose(ptr_file2);
        }
    }

    fclose(ptr_file);
        return 0;
}
```